# Python Access Webservice with Caused by SS Error(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number

Tags: python, web-services, ssl, runtime-error, zeep

Recently, I got a project to push data by the WEB Service. and I installed the zeep a python package and write the following code to test connectivity. but got a long error message.

How to solve this issue?

```
from zeep import Client
wsdl = "https://10.110.168.102:20085/PY900/InvoiceProcessor?WSDL"
client = Client(wsdl)
print(client)
```

the error message is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 349, in connect
  File "urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 372, in ssl_wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 637, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.110.168.102', po
t=20085): Max retries exceeded with url: /PY900/InvoiceProcessor?WSDL (Caused b
 SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c
1131)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "zeep\client.py", line 76, in __init__
  File "zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 92, in __init__
  File "zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 95, in load
  File "zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 155, in _get_xml_document
  File "zeep\loader.py", line 89, in load_external
  File "zeep\transports.py", line 123, in load
  File "zeep\transports.py", line 135, in _load_remote_data
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.110.168.102', port=2
085): Max retries exceeded with url: /PY900/InvoiceProcessor?WSDL (Caused by SS
Error(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:113
)')))
[1692] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\test>test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 349, in connect
  File "urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 372, in ssl_wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 637, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.110.168.102', po
t=20085): Max retries exceeded with url: /PY900/InvoiceProcessor?WSDL (Caused b
 SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c
1131)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "zeep\client.py", line 76, in __init__
  File "zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 92, in __init__
  File "zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 95, in load
  File "zeep\wsdl\wsdl.py", line 155, in _get_xml_document
  File "zeep\loader.py", line 89, in load_external
  File "zeep\transports.py", line 123, in load
  File "zeep\transports.py", line 135, in _load_remote_data
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 600, in get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.110.168.102', port=2
085): Max retries exceeded with url: /PY900/InvoiceProcessor?WSDL (Caused by SS
Error(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:113
)')))
[4800] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

And according to the information in the other posts, I have downgraded the version of urllib3 from the latest to 1.23. but the issue is still there.

did anyone encounter the same issue? please give me some advice.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Educated guess: the server you are trying to access does not support HTTPS, i.e. the URL should be `http://` not `https://`. That's the kind of error you get in this case.

Comment: No, I am sure it's https. but I found there are using SSLV3. but my python version is 3.8 which doesn't support SSLV3 any more. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Seriously SSLv3? This is dead since ages. You have to travel back in Python/OpenSSL versions many years to get a version which still supports this. It is not enough to use an older version of urllib3 since it must be supported by the OpenSSL version which is linked to Python.

Comment: we give up the project. because the web service supplier will not update their SSL version. thans a lot @SteffenUllrich